# integer that becomes 0 in a strange way

Tags: objective-c, c

I have an integer : (using `xcode` for iPhone ) .

```
int wordCounter=1;
```

Later on, when i fill arrays with it-as a pointer,in a for loop, it somehow becomes 0 after it becomes a certain number . i have checked my program many times for bugs, and i realize that i dont even have a decrement on it anywhere . i do have  `wordCounter++`.

Now i have seen that i have many lines like this,that after them it becomes 0 :

```
if(tempBinary[countWords-1][j] != tempBinary[countWords][j])
```

so i was thinking that `countWords-1` decrement it down again and again, is that possible?
i dont have any other decrement or initialization on this variable in my whole program.
i COULD see that when the `tempBinary` defined as size 7, it initialize at 5, and if `tempBinary` is 5, it zeroing on 3 ..
is it possible that the array is overflow and is zeroing it? i dont think so..

whats wrong here ?
thanks .

**EDIT** (one of the problematic states)

```
int countWords=1;  
 int stabilityK=0;

tempBinary[0][0]= tempBinary[0][1]=tempBinary[0][2]=tempBinary[0][3]=tempBinary[0][4]=tempBinary[0][5]=tempBinary[0][6]=tempBinary[0][7]=1 ;

for(int k=0;k<numOfBuffers;k++)
{
    NSLog(@"countwords:%d",countWords-1);
    float *temp=getFFT(buffersRing[k],buffersRing[k][0]);
    for(int j=0;j<wordSize;j++)
    {

        switch(state_on_signal)
        {

            case WAIT_FOR_SECOND_CHANGE:
                //get new word
                if(temp[goodBins[j]] > decisionLine[j])
                    tempBinary[countWords][j]=1;
                else
                    tempBinary[countWords][j]=0;

                if(tempBinary[countWords-1][j] != tempBinary[countWords][j])
                    newData=1;
                  NSLog(@"s1: countwords:%d",countWords-1);
                if(j==wordSize-1)
                {
                    NSLog(@"s2: countwords:%d",countWords-1);
                    NSLog(@"PRE TEMP:%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",tempBinary[countWords-1][0],tempBinary[countWords-1][1],tempBinary[countWords-1][2],tempBinary[countWords-1][3],tempBinary[countWords-1][4],tempBinary[countWords-1][5],tempBinary[countWords-1][6],tempBinary[countWords-1][7] );
                    NSLog(@"NEW TEMP-WAIT FOR SECOND CHANGE :%d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d",tempBinary[countWords][0],tempBinary[countWords][1],tempBinary[countWords][2],tempBinary[countWords][3],tempBinary[countWords][4],tempBinary[countWords][5],tempBinary[countWords][6],tempBinary[countWords][7] );

                    NSLog(@"s3: countwords:%d",countWords-1);
                    //TAKE NEW DATA
                    if(newData==1)
                    {
                             NSLog(@" TOOK new BINARY at current k:%d, so took data at: %d",k,(k+markedK)/2);

                        for(int s=0;s<wordSize;s++)
                        {
                            if( getFFT(buffersRing[(k+markedK)/2],buffersRing[(k+markedK)/2][0])[goodBins[s]  ]  >decisionLine[s] )
                              binary[countWords-1][s]=  1;
                               else
                                binary[countWords-1][s]=  0;

                        }
                        NSLog(@"s4: countwords:%d",countWords-1);
                        NSLog(@"BINARY%d: %d%d%d%d%d%d%d%d :%d",(countWords-1), binary[(countWords-1)][0], binary[(countWords-1)][1], binary[(countWords-1)][2], binary[(countWords-1)][3], binary[(countWords-1)][4], binary[(countWords-1)][5], binary[(countWords-1)][6], binary[(countWords-1)][7],[self getDecimal:binary[countWords-1]]);


                            countWords++;
                            markedK=k;
                            state_on_signal=WAIT_FOR_STABILITY;

                    }
                    newData=0;


                }
                break;
```

Comment: so i was thinking that countWords-1 decrement it down again and again, is that possible?

that's impossible. show all your code

Comment: Is it `countWords` or `wordCounter`? Anyway, it could be an array overflow. Is it declared after a particular array?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Did you post this question forgetting to log in? I have flagged it as such.

Comment: Please show us the code. .

Comment: @Potatoswatter what? i'm sorry, i have no idea what you're talking about

Comment: Wild guess: You're actually having at least two local int variables called wordCounter...

Comment: i have edited with my code .. i dont  have 2 of them i have checked.

Comment: what makes you think it becomes zero? it simply can't become zero at this piece of code. are you sure you don't mess something?

Comment: i have got my problem. if i set it to be static its not happen. i was thinking that this whole function is being called again but i logged that and its not . what is that ??? some kind of releasing the memory?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha it is logging zero on log s1, after it was 6 at the previous log..

Comment: now i can see that if i define this variable out of the function, its also not happening ,BUT the function IS NOT being called again, i have checked that very carefully .i am lost .

Comment: and another discovery : if i do "int countWords" at start of the program , than in the function i do countWords=1. its also NOT happen. so the function IS NOT being called again. WHY DO I HAVE TO DECLARE IT ONLY AT THE START OF MY PROGRAM AS GLOBAL ? OR STATIC IN THE FUNCTION?

Comment: Did you try to check your program for memory leacks?

Comment: As others have stated the int won't suddenly change value on its own within its scope. So, the problem lies elsewhere. You state above that the code is "ONE of the problematic states". Are there other methods using the wordCounter int?  The fact that defining it as an ivar removes the problem strongly suggests that you somehow have several local variables with the same name, perhaps a stray "int" somewhere you just planned to change the value?

Comment: @nickfalk no. its easy to find this variable in a simple search. its not appear anywhere in the program. and not in the other states. i am now pretty sure its a memory thing. because if i clear some memory its not happen. (an array of int_16t [200][1024] is too big for the iPhone? i dont think so..

Comment: Stick a watchpoint on the variable with a condition that it's value becomes `0`.

Comment: i did. it becomes 0 between the first log and the second log on the code below . its crazy.

Comment: A watchpoint is like a break point. It tells you exactly the line of code that caused the variable to change. What exact code line is that?

Comment: Values that misteriously change value are normally due to stray pointers, check that all your pointers are handled sensibly (in particular, get initialized correctly).

Answer (score 1):

> so i was thinking that countWords-1 decrement it down again and again,
>   is that possible?

No

*Usually* this happens when you misuse a pointer and write a value to the wrong address in memory.

For example: where and how is declared **tempBinary** ?

As it's not possible (at least for me) to see the problem just looking at your code I'd suggest to step through your code with the debugger and see when **countWords** gets changed. Here lies the problem (at least one of them).